# is it possible to list all blocked tornado coroutines

Tags: python, tornado

I have a "gateway" app written in `tornado` using `@tornado.gen.coroutine` to transfer information from one handler to another. I'm trying to do some debugging/status testing. What I'd like to be able to do is enumerate all of the currently blocked/waiting coroutines that are live at a given moment. Is this information accessible somewhere in tornado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't, but you could perhaps create your own decorator that wraps gen.coroutine, then updates a data structure when the coroutine begins.

```
import weakref
import functools

from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

all_coroutines = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()


def tracked_coroutine(fn):
    coro = gen.coroutine(fn)

    @functools.wraps(coro)
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        future = coro(*args, **kwargs)
        all_coroutines[future] = str(fn)
        return future

    return start


@tracked_coroutine
def five_second_coroutine():
    yield gen.sleep(5)


@tracked_coroutine
def ten_second_coroutine():
    yield gen.sleep(10)


@gen.coroutine
def tracker():
    while True:
        running = list(all_coroutines.values()) 
        print(running)
        yield gen.sleep(1)


loop = IOLoop.current()
loop.spawn_callback(tracker)
loop.spawn_callback(five_second_coroutine)
loop.spawn_callback(ten_second_coroutine)
loop.start()
```

If you run this script for a few seconds you'll see two active coroutines, then one, then none.

Note the [warning in the docs about the dictionary changing size](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakKeyDictionary), you should catch "RuntimeError" in "tracker" to deal with that problem.

This is a bit complex, you might get all you need much more simply by turning on Tornado's logging and using [set_blocking_log_threshold](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.set_blocking_log_threshold).

Comment: I'm interested in the `set_blocking_log_threshold()` approach. So I added a `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().set_blocking_log_threshold(1)` right before my `...current().start()` line. I have a GET request that I can tell is blocked as a coroutine (it hasn't replied yet), but I don't see anything in a log. I run this as a system script, where *should* I look for the log output? The doc makes it sound like this only happens if if the main thread blocks too long. Not if a handler is blocked as a coroutine. So will this even show what I want?

Comment: It only shows when synchronous code blocks the event loop. If you add a time.sleep(10) to your code, you should see that appear in your Tornado application log. If (without the time.sleep) you have no blocking operations logged, then your code is written correctly - it's async - so my complex approach might actually do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You talk about ioloop `_handlers` dict maybe. Try to add this in periodic callback:

```
def print_current_handlers():
    io_loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    print io_loop._handlers
```

**update**: I've checked source code and now think that there is no simple way to trace current running gen.corouitines, A. Jesse Jiryu Davis is right!

But you can trace all "async" calls (yields) from coroutines - each yield from generator go into `IOLoop.add_callback` (http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#callbacks-and-timeouts)

So, by examining `io_loop._callbacks` you can see what yields are in ioloop right now.

Many interesting stuff is here :)  https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/gen.py

Comment: OK, this looks promising. Not sure how to interpret the output which looks something like: {4: (4, <function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x7f6b6f53a400>),
 6: (<socket.socket fd=6, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=6, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 4443)>,
     <function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x7f6b6f53a620>),
 7: (<socket.socket fd=7, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET6, type=2049, proto=6, laddr=('::', 4443, 0, 0)>,
     <function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x7f6b6f53a730>),
...

Comment: is the `<function wrap...` entry a blocked coroutine?